# Writing file line to Django model field

Tags: python, database, django, file, file-io

I can't seem to write a line from a file to a field of a Django model. The field is described in the model as:

```
 text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='A status message.')
```

However, when I attempt to create a new object I cannot fill this field using the readline function:

```
file = open(filename, 'r')
str = file.readline()
```

When I attempt to use `str` for the text field I don't seem to be able to read or write to the database.  I'm not given any error so I'm assuming its an encoding problem.  Any advice? Thanks.

**edit**

The database is a postgres database and the field type is "text".

The code I'm using to create the object is:

```
Message.objects.create_message(sys, str)
```

and

```
def create_message(self, system, msg):
        """Create a message for the given system."""
        m = Message.objects.create(system=system,
                   text=msg)
        return m
```

Comment: how are you "using str for the textfield"? where's the rest of the code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Don't create variable names which conflict with python built in types. "str" is the string type.Python interpreter:

```
>> str
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: Thanks, changed that but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not calling the `create_message` method properly. Shouldn't you just call it like this

```
create_message(sys, str)
```

instead of this

```
Message.objects.create_message(sys, str)
```

?